# Spring Web Security entry point triggers

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am getting started with Spring Web Security for my application and I am trying to implement stateless JWT authentication. Curretly, the configure method in the Web Security config is the following

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/register", "/authenticate/{uuid}").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        ;

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

My jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint is the following:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        log.warn("Responding with unauthorized error. Message - {}", authException.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Sorry, You're not authorized to access this resource.");
    }
}
```

The authentication works correctly besides for the `"/authenticate/{uuid}"` endpoint. The request is allowed (Status 200 and correct return of the function) but I keep getting the warning from the `jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint` class ("Responding with unauthorized error") in the console.

Why is the EntryPoint getting triggered for that specific request and how can I resolve it?

EDIT:
AuthenticationController:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class AuthenticationController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate/{uuid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticate(@PathVariable String uuid){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(uuid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide /authenticate/{uuid} controller?

Comment: @MikheilZhghenti added as an edit

Comment: Try this way: authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate/**").permitAll().... build with all required endpoints this way (/**).

Comment: @MikheilZhghenti same results sadly

Answer (score 0):

Pls use  web.ignoring() to try as the below:

```java
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        String [] notauthlist = new String[]{"/login", "/register","/authenticate/**"};
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(notauthlist);
    }

   protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        ;

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```